# How to add list values and quantity to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write a for loop that will take a list and add its values to a dictionary. For example let's say a list contains the values: [Book, Coin, Book, Book, Computer, Bag]. the for loop will take those values and add it to a dictionary with its keys being the name of the items added and the corresponding values being the quantity of the items. Here is the code i have so far:

```
import pprint

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory += addedItems.count(i)

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        pprint.pprint(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

stuff = {}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

# while True:
#     item = raw_input('Please enter item name')
#     if item == '':
#         break
#     quantity = input('and the number of this item?')
#     stuff.setdefault(item, quantity)
#     print stuff

stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

Comment: Could you provide a more thorough example for : [Book, Coin, Book, Book, Computer, Bag]? Would the result be {"Book":3, "Coin":1, "Computer":1, "Bag":1}?

Comment: Yes, that's what the output would be.

Comment: So use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: I think you may be having issues with a non-empty dictionary and always overriding the counts with what ever is in the list.

Comment: Or keep your current way but use `inventory[i] = inventory.get(i, 0) + 1` in your `addToInventory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. The key is to only iterate through the unique items in the new list and add to the existing dictionary or update the item if it doesn't exist.

```
alist = ["Book", "Coin", "Book", "Book", "Computer", "Bag"]
inventory = {"Book":3, "Bag":2}
for item in list(set(alist)): #get the unique items by converting them to a set
    if item in result:
        inventory[item] += alist.count(item) 
    else:
        inventory[item] = alist.count(item)

#inventory would now become {"Book":6, "Coin":1", "Bag":3", "Computer":1}
```

Also, using Stefan's approach.
If inventory is a counter, you could just do

```
inventory.update(alist)
```

Comment: If `inventory` is a Counter, you can just say `inventory.update(alist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def add_to_inventory(inventory, items):
    inventory.update(items)

def display_inventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    print('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(v, k) for k, v in inventory.items()))
    print("Total number of items: {}".format(sum(inventory.values())))

stuff = Counter({'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12})

dragon_loot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

display_inventory(stuff)
add_to_inventory(stuff, dragon_loot)
display_inventory(stuff)
```

**OUTPUT**

> Inventory:
>
> 1 rope
>
> 42 gold coin
>
> 6 torch
>
> 1 dagger
>
> 12 arrow
>
> Total number of items: 62
>
> Inventory:
>
> 45 gold coin
>
> 2 dagger
>
> 6 torch
>
> 1 rope
>
> 12 arrow
>
> 1 ruby
>
> Total number of items: 67

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collection.Counter`:

```
>>> alist = ["Book", "Coin", "Book", "Book", "Computer", "Bag"]
>>> inventory = {"Book":3, "Bag":2}
>>> dict(collections.Counter(inventory) + collections.Counter(alist))
{'Bag': 3, 'Book': 6, 'Coin': 1, 'Computer': 1}
```